# Suppose A and B represent two vectors (insame order), the angle between them being 60 degrees, then why is the resultant wrong?

Tags: vectors, geometry

Let's say there are three points A,B and C:
**A** represents the displacement between points A and B (4 cm to the east) and **B** represents the displacement between the points B and C (3cm to the northwest).And the angle formed ( anglevCBA) is 60 degrees.

The (magnitude of) resultant vector C would be:
[image]

So, according to the triangle law of addition , the answer should be:$\sqrt{37}$ or 6.08
I made a diagram (with some precision), which looked something like:
[image]

On actual construction, I found the magnitude of the resultant to be 3.62  (maybe it was 3.65 cm. Somewhere between 3.60 and 3.70. The point is, it wasn't 6.08 cm.- {Quite far from it}).
The question is/are:

- What did I do wrong?
- Is there something wrong with my interpretation of vector addition?
- And the important question: How do we show this triangle addition law 
  visually? (since, this doesn't seem correct )

// Didn't see any 'beginner' tag in the search result while posting this question

Comment: I don't know where you found it but the cosine rule you're using is just wrong... it should be $a^2 = b^2 +c^2 -2bc \times cos(\theta)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re *adding* $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$, and your formula is correct as long as you take $\theta$ to be the angle between them, which is 120 degrees, not 60. Pay attention to the direction of the vectors.

Comment: 120 degrees was in the exercise question. I was trying to find out whether it holds true for acute angles. How's the angle 120 degrees in this case(given the diagram)?

Comment: A vector is a quantity with a magnitude and a direction. Its base point (where its tail end is) is irrelevant. So slide $\vec{A}$ so that its tail is at B, where $\vec {B}$’s tail is. Now look at the angle between them.

Comment: Here’s another way to think about it. If I am moving east in the direction to $\vec{A}$, by what angle do I have to turn counterclockwise to face in the northwest direction of $\vec{B}$?

Comment: Thanks! Got that now.

Comment: Your vector addition formula does hold for all angles, but in this case the angle is obtuse.

Comment: Kind of funny. I was thinking it was acute in this case and obtuse in all others.

Comment: Other folks didn’t notice that the vectors were being added. If you reverse the arrow on $\vec{A}$, then $\vec{C}=\vec{B}-\vec{A}$, their formulas with the minus sign apply, and the angle between the vectors is 60 degrees. Plus they have the same base so it is easier to understand what the angle is! So this way of thinking about a triangle of vectors is much more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you misplaced a $+$ where it should be a $-$:
$$ c^2=a^2+b^2-2\,a\,b\,\cos\gamma $$
With this, we get a length of $c=3.61\text{ cm.}$